# How can I test a TCP connection to a server with C# given the server's IP address and port?

Tags: c#, networking

How can I *programmatically* determine if I have access to a server (TCP) with a given IP address and port using C#?

Comment: Some clarification is necessary.  What does "access" mean?  Are you attempting to connect to a particular port on the target machine?

Comment: I've updated the question to be more specific (TCP access given IP+port)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you mean through a TCP socket:

```
IPAddress IP;
if(IPAddress.TryParse("127.0.0.1",out IP)){
    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try{   
        s.Connect(IPs[0], port);
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // something went wrong
    }
}
```

For more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xzx2d41.aspx?ppud=4

Comment: The instance of IP created upon declaration will never be used because it's immediately passed as an out parameter, which will always be replaced inside the method called.  So I would leave the instantiation out.  But you can't without changing IP.TryParse to IPAddress.TryParse (it's a static method).  So I would change that too.

Comment: change IP[0] to only IP

Answer (score 12):

Declare string address and int port and you are ready to connect through the TcpClient class.

```
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
try
{
    client.Connect(address, port);
    Console.WriteLine("Connection open, host active");
} catch (SocketException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Connection could not be established due to: \n" + ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    client.Close();
}
```

Answer (score -4):

This should do it

```
bool ssl;
ssl = false;
int maxWaitMillisec;
maxWaitMillisec = 20000;
int port = 555;

success = socket.Connect("Your ip address",port,ssl,maxWaitMillisec);


if (success != true) {

    MessageBox.Show(socket.LastErrorText);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Where do you define socket? This code snippet is incomplete.