# C# Check Remote Server

Tags: c#, .net

Can anyone advise what the best way to check (using .NET 3.5) if a remote server is available?

I was thinking of using the following code but would like to know if a better way exists if the community has another option.

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient("MyServer", 80);
if (!client.Connected)
{
    throw new Exception("Unable to connect to MyServer on Port 80");
}
client.Close();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could [ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) it

You could [download the default page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstring.aspx) from it

You could do a [HEAD](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/2c13cafc-be1c-4dd8-9129-f82f59991517/the-lowly-http-head-reque.aspx) request

If it's a local IIS6 server on your network, and you have some admin details, you could [connect to IIS](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/Start_Stop_IIS_Website.aspx) using some DirectoryEntry code

Some of the answers on [136615](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136615/how-can-i-test-a-connection-to-a-server-with-c-given-the-servers-ip-address) might help too, specifically the accepted answer that talks about [sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4xzx2d41.aspx?ppud=4)

For the print servers (or, specifically, the printers), the code by K Scott [here](http://www.odetocode.com/Humor/68.aspx) might help. It's fun code to play with anyway :-) That code mentions dns.resolve, which is obsoleted and replaced by [Dns.GetHostEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143998.aspx)

I'm about out of ideas :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you just want to see whether a given server is online, then a simple ping should do the job in most cases.

```
PingReply pingReply;
using (var ping = new Ping())
    pingReply = ping.Send("http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
var available = pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
```

Using this method you're not abusing the HTTP server in any way, too.

Otherwise (if you want to check whether a connection is possible on a specific port), that basically looks fine.

Comment: I was under the impression that using the Ping object was not advisable in a corporate intranet or within a firewalled network? I probably should have put that I want to check for availability on a corporate network. Can anyone comment?

Comment: @Kane: Why wouldn't it be advisable? A ping is the standard, tried and tested, way for checking availability of a host. Opening lots of HTTP connections and doing nothing is more likely to amount to abuse/malice. If the ping port is closed, then that's a different matter - however, it *ought* to be open.

Comment: I thought that Ping might not work if a firewall blocks the Ping (ICMP Echo) packets? Could this be true as I really don't know?

Comment: Admittedly I don't work on a corporate network, but I haven't seen ping blocked on any of the larger accademic institutions networks to which I have had access. This is probably because ping is used so frequently by network admins for checking network connectivity

Comment: Many corporates block ICMP on the firewall meaning you can't ping external sites. The site I currently work on does exactly this. Ping just tells you if that server is actively responding to ICMP Echo. If you're testing a web server a request to the service would tell you if the service is working, which is a different thing to responding to ICMP Echo.

Answer (score 4):

just to add to Dan's answer...
I just had to implement this and here is a nice little code snippet that should help out those that make it here from Google.

```
Imports System.Net
Private Function URLExists(pURL As String) As Boolean

    Try
        'Creating the HttpWebRequest
        Dim request As HttpWebRequest = TryCast(WebRequest.Create(pURL), HttpWebRequest)
        'Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
        request.Method = "HEAD"
        'Getting the Web Response.
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = TryCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        'Returns TURE if the Status code == 200
        Return (response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK)
    Catch
        'Any exception will returns false.
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

sorry it is VB but that is what I had in front of me. I will leave it as an exercise for the reader to convert this to C# as needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you be using a previous version of .NET Framework, like me, the version 2, you'll have no Ping and no `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()`. Then, you can use `HttpWebRequest` to check a host disponibility:

```
  public static bool AccessToWebService()
  {
      string host = "http://192.168.99.41";
      try
      {
          HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(host);
          request.Method = "HEAD";
          HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
          return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
      }
      catch (Exception)
      {
          return false;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want to check to see if a website is available. You could just use a [`System.Net.WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and check the result.

**Update:** 
Based on your comment, if you've got a few servers (and services) to monitor, then maybe it'd be a better idea to use a package such as [Nagios](http://nagios.com/), [HostMonitor](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/index.htm) or [IPSentry](http://www.ipsentry.com/) instead of rolling your own.

Comment: I need to check a number of servers. Some of which are web servers some a simple Windows based file/print servers.