# Directory.Exist - Find out if there was a timeout or dir does not exist

Tags: c#, .net, networking, file-io

Say I have a share on a shiny server:

```
\\server1\MyShare
```

If I run this:

```
Directory.Exists("\\server1\MyShare") //Returns True
```

Now I yank the cable out of the server and run the code again:

```
Directory.Exists("\\server1\MyShare") //Returns False
```

I want to know if it returns false because....:

- The server was unreachable
- The server was responsive, but the directory did not exist

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These answers will help out with part a) of your question - how do I check if a remote server is responding: [C# Check Remote Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043342/c-sharp-check-remote-server)

As for part b) your `Directory.Exists` method is the best way - however you might want to look into using WMI to check the folder however this will be much slower and cumbersome than using what you already have..

Answer (score 2):

Check if you can ping the server

[NET Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Ping the server:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx

A blocking example:

```
Ping ping = new Ping();
PingResponse response = ping.PingHost(@"\\server1", 4);
```

Comment: Ah yeah. Ever seen a windows standard setup? For some reason they do not activate all the printer functionality including ICMP (no joke, check advanced firewall rules, this is part of the printer group).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, but as the directory I was after was an extra layer down (`\\Server\Share\Directory`) I was able to cheat with a simple;

```
if( Directory.Exists("\\Server\Share") && !Directory.Exists("\\Server\Share\Directory") )
//Server is up, directory doesn't exist
..etc..
```

There is a potential timing/race condition, but it's yet to cause me any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Pinging is a bit clumsy and depending on how your network is set up pinging may not be allowed or another device may respond to the pings.

This code will write one of three messages to the console depending on the state of the folder you're trying to access:

```
       try
        {
            DirectoryInfo diNoServer = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\non.existant.server\share");
            diNoServer.Attributes = diNoServer.Attributes;
            if (!diNoServer.Exists)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The server was responsive, but the directory did not exist");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("all good");
            }
        }
        catch (IOException exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The server was unreachable");
        }
```

Comment: If I use `"\\ExistingOnlineServer\NonExistantShare"` I hit the "Server was unreachable" catch.

Comment: So it does, thanks @GarethWilson, it looks like I get identical IOExceptions for both "path not found" and "server not found" even though I'd expected .Exists to be false for "path not found".

Answer (score 0):

Typically, if the share is not accessible, something is wrong and processing should stop.

I use the following extension to throw an exception in case the share is not accessible for some reason (network down, server down, forbidden access, etc)

```
public static class DirectoryExtension
{
    public static bool IsShareAccessible(String unc)
    {
        if (Path.IsPathRooted(unc))
        {
            var share = Path.GetPathRoot(unc);
            return Directory.Exists(share);
        }
        return true; //true is is not unc or full local path
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
if (!Directory.IsShareAccessible(@"\\server\share\folder"))
   Throw new ApplicationException("can't access share");

if (!Directory.Exists(@"\\server\share\folder")  {
...
```