# How to check a server is alive?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, active-directory

I want to check a server if it is alive or not without using Ping() method.

Are there any solutions to to that?

At the current the method below is ok to me.

```
public static bool PingToServer(string ipServer)
    {
        bool isServerLife = false;
        try
        {
            Ping ping = new Ping();
            PingReply pingReply = ping.Send(ipServer, 5000);

            if (pingReply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            {
                isServerLife = true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write("PingToServer: Cannot ping to server, " + e.Message);
        }
        return isServerLife;
    }
```

Comment: So you can ping a machine but it is still not responsive?

Comment: check selected answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043342/c-sharp-check-remote-server).

Comment: Just because you can ping it doesn't mean any of the applications are running on the box. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an Active Directory Server as tagged in your question. You can check port `389` or `3268`.

```
public static bool IsADSAlive(String hostName) 
{
    try {
        using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient()) 
        {
           tcpClient.Connect(hostName, 3268);
           return true; 
        } 
    }  catch (SocketException) { 

      return false ; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What are they (389 and 3268) do for?

Comment: As a mentionned above, if you have an Active Directory Server as tagged in your question, you should check 389 or 3268. If you have a web server you can check 80.If you have a ftp server you can check 21, ...

Comment: we should only check one of them or both?

Comment: one of them will be enough.

Comment: If administrator changes to another ports, what should we do to detect them?

Comment: that case you'd better do a port scan or just ask him.