# C# Handling TCP timeouts when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, tcp, connection-timeout

I have created a C# .NET 4.7 application that connects to several different remote SQL database instances. Sometimes connection issues may prevent the connection at a network level.

Presently I'm handling SQL timeout connections with the below code which works fine if a connection exists, but if the issue is at the network level I need to handle these, of which the timeouts are much longer.

I found an article written over 10 years ago here http://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts/. I was wondering if anyone could recommend whether this is current best practice or whether there is a better solution?

```
    if ( e is SqlException f)
            {
                if (f.Number == -2 | f.Number == 258)
                {  do stuff} 
            }
```

Comment: The connection should be instant unless the server is chained, or there is a proxy and the proxy timed out.

Comment: some of the servers are remote via vpn so I need to handle whether the connection is available or whether someone has switched the computer off!.

Comment: Lengthening the timeout is not going to fix a problem where the server is turned off.   It is just going to prolong the time it takes to discover that the server is turned off.  The default timeout is 30 seconds and it would be better to shorten the timeout rather than have somebody wait 30 seconds for the error.  You probably want to add an exception handler to capture the timeout and then determine what to do next.

Comment: When the server is turned off though the sql timeout doesn't seem to be triggered at 30 seconds runs what seems like indefinitely so I figure it was probably a network level timeout TCP which is 15minutes?

Comment: should I test connection first ? something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/136615/how-can-i-test-a-connection-to-a-server-with-c-sharp-given-the-servers-ip-addre

Comment: No Connection Timeout is 15 minutes.  The connection timeout is the time to complete a connection.  If you are getting a 15 minute timeout, then the server is disconnecting when the connection is idle.  To keep channel open you  would need a KeepAlive which sends an empty message every few seconds so the server will not disconnect.

Comment: Thanks but this article does state that TCP timeouts are 15 minutes. http://improve.dk/controlling-sqlconnection-timeouts/

Comment: There is no 15 minutes on the link.

Comment: TCP default time is 15 minutes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853676/how-to-avoid-sql-query-timeout.. Confirmed that above code still valid and solves issue.. tweaked it slightly for my project..

Comment: That posting from 2009 says nothing about the connection timeout taking 15 minutes.  The 15 minutes could be the amount of time it takes to complete the query.  When making the initial connection the default timeout is 30 seconds.  Do not confuse the connection time with the query time.